# What do I do with my stamps now?

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins

I amassed millions of stamps in order to buy unicoins<sup>1</sup>.  It turns out that SE won't accept those now.

[image]

What do I do with my stamps now?  I feel cheated.

<sup>1</sup> Sources had told me that it's be soon possible to trade unicoins for bitcoins.

Comment: Isn't that an _Apris Fool_'s joke? Any chances, they start to accept them ([whatever this strange thing is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227511/189165)) like... tomorrow?

Comment: *You* feel cheated? http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2014/apr/01/royal-mail-undervaluing-taxpayer-cable (and despite the date, the Royal Mail sale/undervalue was genuine)

Comment: I suggest you send one million angry letters to the Stack Exchange Headquarters. Or half a million, each one including a self-addressed stamped envelope for the unicoins you are owed.

Comment: @MarcGravell Good that a diamond mod responded.  Yes, I feel cheated.  I'll now need to do away with my stamps at throwaway prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever wonder why the unicorn in the unicoin widget has its tongue sticking out? That's because it wants to lick stamps and give you unicoins. I found a workaround for the technical issue, and you just have to do this:

1. Remove stamp
2. Push stamp onto monitor, on top of unicoin widget
3. Wait
4. ???
5. PROFIT!!!

I earned 500 unicoins a day just by using this 1 simple trick!*

**Satisfaction not guaranteed.*